# shifting data in python in different steps

Tags: python, pandas, function, numpy, shift

Please correct me if I am using the wrong vocabular. I want to shift my data with different steps. I found this one to shift by 1 for a variable window size:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

a=np.random.rand(30)
series=pd.DataFrame(a)
window_size = 3
series_s = series.copy()
for i in range(window_size):
    series = pd.concat([series, series_s.shift(-(i+1))], axis = 1)

series.dropna(axis=0, inplace=True)
```

here I am shifting like this (dots just for how it would go on) :

```
5 6  4    
6 4  3    
4 3  8    
3 8  9    
8 9  10    
9 10 .    
10 . .
```

what I want to do is shifting e.g. by 2:

```
5 4  8
6 3  9    
4 8 10   
3 9  .    
8 10 .    
9  . .    
10 . .
```

how do I have to change the code above or how I can do this ?

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is define a variable called cumulative lag.
For example, let window size = n, and lag_rate of 2, the original column will have zero lag, the first column will have lag of 2 relative to the original column, the second will have lag of 4 relative to the first column, and nth column will have lag of 2*n relative to the first column

Modifying your code slightly for readability:

```
#set up the variables
a=np.random.rand(30)
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['original'] = a
window_size = 3
lag_by_rate = 2
```

Now I will begin to iterate over the window_size parameter to generate new columns. Notice you should start the for loop at 1 instead of zero, because if you start it at zero, you essentially duplicate the original column of the dataframe

```
for i in range(1, window_size):
    cum_lag = i * lag_by_rate
    col_name = 'lag_by_'+str(cum_lag)
    df[col_name] =  df.original.shift(-cum_lag)
```

Lastly I use the dropna function and print the head:

```
df.dropna(axis=0, inplace=True)
print(df.head())
```

An example of my output:

```
    original    lag_by_2    lag_by_4
0   0.595142    0.625494    0.812595
1   0.822615    0.582148    0.778157
2   0.625494    0.812595    0.693790
3   0.582148    0.778157    0.416109
4   0.812595    0.693790    0.748151
```

For what it's worth, you would lose data at a significant rate with this approach. If the ratio of len(df)/window_size == lag_rate, you would end up getting zero rows in the dataframe after you drop the N/A values

Further to your comment below, I substituted the values that you mentioned in your example, and I get the same output:

```
    original    lag_by_2    lag_by_4
0   5           4.0         8.0
1   6           3.0         9.0
2   4           8.0         10.0
```

Comment: @I changed what I am trying to do now looks a bit different. I made a mistake in my explanation please check it. I alway want to lag by 2 not 4 or 6 later and so on.

Comment: Hi, you always want to lag by 2, relative to the previous column. That's equivalent to lagging by 2*(w-1) for the w-th column. If I substitute your original array of [5,6,4,3,8,9,10] I get exactly the output you require in your question

Comment: @thanks yes I was confused. It works as I wanted. I now I am going to lose data but thats what I am trying to see what will happen.

Answer (score 2):

**`shift`** returns a copy of your dataframe, it does not modify it, so creating a copy is unnecessary.

You can further clean up your code by using a list comprehension, and use a bit of algebra to shift by two each column instead of one.

```
x = np.random.randint(1, 10, 10)
df = pd.DataFrame(x)
dfs = [df.shift(-(2+2*i)) for i in range(3)]

pd.concat([df, *dfs], axis=1)

   0    0    0    0
0  3  1.0  3.0  8.0
1  9  1.0  6.0  8.0
2  1  3.0  8.0  1.0
3  1  6.0  8.0  9.0
4  3  8.0  1.0  NaN
5  6  8.0  9.0  NaN
6  8  1.0  NaN  NaN
7  8  9.0  NaN  NaN
8  1  NaN  NaN  NaN
9  9  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

This approach does leave you with the same column header for each column, which you could fix using something like:

```
df_result.columns = range(len(df_result.columns))
```